# Reading data from a Database in a thread-safe manner

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, atomicreference

In my app I have a "Manager" class that has a reference to a DAO class which loads data from DB and populate a HashMap as a cache solution.

Here is a snippet

```
class UserManager {
   private final UserDAO userDAO;

   private final Map<Long, User> users;
   private final StampedLock lock = new StampedLock();

   public UserManager() {
     loadUsersFromDB();
   }

   // 99% of the times this method is called
   public getUserById(long id) {
      long stamp = lock.readLock();
       try {
         return users.get(id);
       } finally {
         lock.unlock(stamp);
       }
   }
 
   // This is done once when CTOR calls it and from time to time
   // by explicitly calling it from outside.
   public void loadUsersFromDB() {
 
      Map<Long, User> loadedUsers = userDAO.loadUsers();       

      long stamp = lock.writeLock();
      try {
        this.users = loadedUsers;
        
      } finally {
        lock.unlock(stamp);
      }
   }
}
```

This code work in a multithreaded environment, and the concern here is the use of `StampedLock` in this situation is an OVERKILL since most of the time it does READ operations and once in a while a simple load from DB and assignment to a class member.

I'm thinking to remove the `StampedLock` and instead use a simple `AtomicReference<Map<Long, User>>`, this way most of the time it's going to be a simple `get` and once in a while a `set`.

What do you think??

Comment: With `AtomicReference`, don't you have to copy the `Map` when you make a change in your cache, to keep it immutable? Otherwise I don't see how it would work out. It may be a good idea to measure the time required to do this copy, and how many times you'll have to do it.

Comment: Why not just use a `ConcurrentHashMap`. Quote from javadoc: "even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access"

Comment: @TacheDeChoco : Because `ConcurrentHashMap` uses a standard synchronization, while `AtomicReference` uses hardware to make sure the variable is volatile; this is much faster and lock-free.

Comment: @TacheDeChoco : I'm not considering using `ConcurrentHashMap` because when I call `reload` it actually swap references between old map and new map freshly loaded from DB. That's why I'm considering `AtomicReference`.

Comment: @Guillaume F.   : Yes, that's exactly why I believe `AtomicReference` is a good fit. I load data from DB and set it in a `Map` and then use `AtomicRereference#set` to swap old `Map` with the new one. Makes sense? 
While `set` is called no other thread can invoke `get`.

Comment: Makes sense to me.